# MATLAB, How to visualize my directional beam Data

Tags: matlab

I've made an experiment with directional beams and I would like to visualise it. The set-up was like this:

[image: setup]

I've measured my values at 22, 15, 10, 5 and 0 degrees in a distance of 100, 75, 50 and 25 cm.

Now I would like to bring this Data into a 3D **`waterfall()`** diagram where the source is the highest peak and you can see that the voltage decreases in all directions.

So my first thought was to fit all distances individually and these functions I would like to put them into the **`waterfall()`**. But this doesn't work very well, because the begin and end different layers of values (have a look at the example code) after I calculate them to the `x`, `y` system was different.

So, how can I bring my data into a waterfall diagram?

```
clearvars
x=-1:0.1:1;

%________________________________________________________measured Values (layers)
A=[208; 256; 480; 704; 776; 752; 672; 480; 264];  % 0.25m
B=[104; 156; 304; 388; 432; 440; 340; 280; 140];  % 0.50m
C=[ 54; 104; 250; 264; 320; 270; 252; 144;  70];  % 0.75m
D=[ 32;  64; 142; 198; 228; 208; 130;  86;  46;]; % 1.00m

% plot(A)
% figure(2)
% plot(B)
% figure(3)
% plot(C)
% figure(4)
% plot(D)

%________________________________________________________to x,y System
dist1=[tand(-22)*0.25; tand(-15)*0.25; tand(-10)*0.25; tand(-5)*0.25; tand(0)*0.25; tand(5)*0.25; tand(10)*0.25; tand(15)*0.25; tand(22)*0.25;];
dist2=[tand(-22)*0.50; tand(-15)*0.50; tand(-10)*0.50; tand(-5)*0.50; tand(0)*0.50; tand(5)*0.50; tand(10)*0.50; tand(15)*0.50; tand(22)*0.50;];
dist3=[tand(-22)*0.75; tand(-15)*0.75; tand(-10)*0.75; tand(-5)*0.75; tand(0)*0.75; tand(5)*0.75; tand(10)*0.75; tand(15)*0.75; tand(22)*0.75;];
dist4=[tand(-22);      tand(-15);      tand(-10);      tand(-5);      tand(0);      tand(5);      tand(10);      tand(15);      tand(22)];

plot(dist1,A)
figure(2)
plot(dist2,B)
figure(3)
plot(dist3,C)
figure(4)
plot(dist4,D)

% func1= fit(dist1,A,'poly2')
% 
% plot(dist1, func1(dist1))
```

Furthermore:

As a result I would like to create something like this:

[image]

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waterfall.html

or maybe a surface:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html

But I don't know how I can convert my current data into a format, which fits the requirements of the **`waterfall()`** or **`surf()`** function

Comment: what do you mean by "_waterfall_" diagram (link an existing picture if you can) and what are the variables `ab1` to `ab4` (how are they built) ?

Comment: im sorry abs1-4 are the same as dist1-4 i will change this

Comment: do you just want the 4 plots in the same `figure/axis` ?

Comment: I've add a picture, hopefully this show my intension

Comment: Thank you Daniel, Hoki and JJM Driessen for your Answers. All 3 worked fine for my problem! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about organizing your data. As Daniel said, `waterfall` (or even `surf` for that matter) require a *mesh* as input (your data need to be matrices).

So let's build a proper mesh with your data:

```
%% // measured Values (layers)
A = [208; 256; 480; 704; 776; 752; 672; 480; 264] ; %// 0.25m
B = [104; 156; 304; 388; 432; 440; 340; 280; 140] ; %// 0.50m
C = [ 54; 104; 250; 264; 320; 270; 252; 144;  70] ; %// 0.75m
D = [ 32;  64; 142; 198; 228; 208; 130;  86;  46] ; %// 1.00m

%% // Building the mesh
%// primary parameters
x      = (0.25:0.25:1).' ;                       %'// ignore that comment
angles = [-22 -15 -10 -5 0 5 10 15 22] ;

%// mesh matrices
X = x * ones(1,numel(angles)) ; %// distance to source
Y = x * tand(angles) ;          %// lateral spread due to angle
V = [A B C D].' ;               %'// measurements (voltages)
```

At this point, you have 3 matrices `X`,`Y` and `V` which are perfect input for most 3D graphing functions like `surf` or `waterfall`. So it becomes quite straightforward:

```
%% // Waterfall visualisation
hf = figure ;
hw = waterfall(X,Y,V) ;
```

If you want to add some refinements :

```
%% // refinements
shading interp
xlabel('Distance to source')
ylabel('Lateral spread')
zlabel('Voltage')
hold on
plot3(0,0,0,'or','MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth',4) %// show the source position
```

and/or even more information on the figure:

```
%% // displays the base rays
xrays = [0;x] ;
yrays = [zeros(1,numel(angles)) ; Y] ;

set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[0 0 0] , 'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder','--|:' )
plot(xrays,yrays,'Marker','.')
```

At this stage, it yields the following figure, but you can keep it simple or adjust many other properties of all the graphic object to personalize your display:
[image: waterfall]

---

You can also play with the `surf` function instead of `waterfall`, and use the same matrices as input.

---

Another way to better link the voltage recorded for every sensor position would be to use a `stem` plot. Unfortunately the `stem` function does not take 3D arrays as input, however, the `ZData` property still exist so we can instantiate the stem plot first then loop through them to set their `ZData`:

```
%% // STEM waterfall variant
hsf = figure ; hold on
hs = stem(X.',Y.',':ob') ;
for k=1:4
    set(hs(k),'ZData',V(k,:))
end
```

With all the refinements above, it yields:

[image: stem waterfall]

This variant doesn't color code the voltage but it shows exactly the position where it was recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to mesh your data first (i.e. put them in X, Y and Z matrices):

```
%Z:
dist1234=[dist1 dist2 dist3 dist4];
%Y:
ABCD=[A B C D];
%X:
[n1,n2]=size(ABCD);
X=repmat(1:n2,n1,1); % or whatever your x-axis is, here it is 1, 2, 3...

% Take your pick:
figure(1)
surf(X,dist1234,ABCD);title('surf')
figure(2)
waterfall(X',dist1234',ABCD');title('waterfall')
figure(3)
mesh(X,dist1234,ABCD);title('mesh')
```

[image: DEOS3.png]
[image: JDS9r.png]
[image: kpIrW.png]